# Sum values of a column for each month of each year

Tags: r

I have a CSV containing rainfall measurement for each day of each month over several years. I would like to have as output the rainfall for each month over this period of years. So, I would like to sum the rainfall `prtotAdjust` for each month `Mois` of each year `An`.

I tried following:

```
data <- read.csv2('./data.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ";", 
                  dec = ".",skip=48,
                  col.names=c("An","Mois","Jour","tasAdjust","prtotAdjust"),
                  colClasses=c("factor","factor","factor","numeric",
                               "numeric"))

aggregate(prtotAdjust ~ Mois + An, data, sum)
```

The output for the first year is:

```
   Mois   An    prtotAdjust
1     01 1951   17067.684
2     02 1951    8519.292
3     03 1951   20231.261
4     04 1951    5166.890
5     05 1951   16022.496
6     06 1951    5879.282
7     07 1951   12741.223
8     08 1951   21018.112
9     09 1951    8526.597
10    10 1951    5456.381
11    11 1951   14463.811
12    12 1951    7308.237
```

The problem is that the outputs are not correct because when I do the calculation by hand the values are different. Example for the month of January, according to the code the result is  `17067.684` but it should be `75.17`.

Here a sample of the first month:

```
An;Mois;Jour;prtotAdjust
1951;1;1;0.00
1951;1;2;0.00
1951;1;3;0.00
1951;1;4;0.00
1951;1;5;0.43
1951;1;6;0.64
1951;1;7;6.89
1951;1;8;4.71
1951;1;9;2.21
1951;1;10;0.50
1951;1;11;6.09
1951;1;12;0.00
1951;1;13;0.59
1951;1;14;0.76
1951;1;15;4.82
1951;1;16;17.39
1951;1;17;0.93
1951;1;18;4.09
1951;1;19;6.21
1951;1;20;3.09
1951;1;21;5.41
1951;1;22;0.94
1951;1;23;1.42
1951;1;24;0.00
1951;1;25;4.36
1951;1;26;3.65
1951;1;27;0.06
1951;1;28;0.00
1951;1;29;0.00
1951;1;30;0.00
1951;1;31;0.00
```

How can I get the expected result?

Comment: It's hard for us to tell what is going on when we don't have access to the data.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you for your comment. I added a sample in the edit.

Comment: Using the this data, I get the expected result `75.19`. I guess you'll want to check that you import your data correctly into R.

Answer (score 1):

The `read.csv` command in the question refers to 5 fields but the data shown only has 4. Using the input in the Note at the end this works:

```
data <- read.csv(text = Lines, sep = ";")
aggregate(prtotAdjust ~ Mois + An, data, sum)
##   Mois   An prtotAdjust
## 1    1 1951       75.19
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "An;Mois;Jour;prtotAdjust
1951;1;1;0.00
1951;1;2;0.00
1951;1;3;0.00
1951;1;4;0.00
1951;1;5;0.43
1951;1;6;0.64
1951;1;7;6.89
1951;1;8;4.71
1951;1;9;2.21
1951;1;10;0.50
1951;1;11;6.09
1951;1;12;0.00
1951;1;13;0.59
1951;1;14;0.76
1951;1;15;4.82
1951;1;16;17.39
1951;1;17;0.93
1951;1;18;4.09
1951;1;19;6.21
1951;1;20;3.09
1951;1;21;5.41
1951;1;22;0.94
1951;1;23;1.42
1951;1;24;0.00
1951;1;25;4.36
1951;1;26;3.65
1951;1;27;0.06
1951;1;28;0.00
1951;1;29;0.00
1951;1;30;0.00
1951;1;31;0.00"
```